# OData function returning a collection of entities fails with PowerQuery

Tags: java, json, olingo

I got this error while using PowerQuery on a OData service I’m currently developing:

> When writing a JSON response, a user model must be specified and the
>   entity set and entity type must be passed to the
>   ODataMessageWriter.CreateODataEntryWriter method or the
>   ODataFeedAndEntrySerializationInfo must be set on the ODataEntry or
>   ODataFeed that is being written.

This occurs when invoking from PowerQuery a bound function that returns a collection of entities. When invoked from a web browser, the response is (JSON format):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:8080/ODataPrototype/ODataPrototype.svc/$metadata#Collection(Demo.ODataPrototype.Count)",
    "value": [
        {
            "RowCount": 1
        },
        {
            "RowCount": 2
        },
        {
            "RowCount": 3
        },
        {
            "RowCount": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I use the Olingo V4 library. A stripped down version of my metadata would be:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Demo.ODataPrototype">
      <EntityType Name="Instance">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Tag" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Xid" Type="Edm.Int64" />
        <Property Name="Properties" Type="Collection(Demo.ODataPrototype.Property)" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Count">
        <Property Name="RowCount" Type="Edm.Int32" />
      </EntityType>
      <ComplexType Name="Property">
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Value" Type="Edm.String" />
      </ComplexType>
      <Function Name="GetData" EntitySetPath="Instance/Demo.ODataPrototype.Count" IsBound="true">
        <Parameter Name="Instance" Type="Demo.ODataPrototype.Instance" />
        <Parameter Name="From" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
        <Parameter Name="To" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
        <ReturnType Type="Collection(Demo.ODataPrototype.Count)" />
      </Function>
      <EntityContainer Name="Container">
        <EntitySet Name="Instances" EntityType="Demo.ODataPrototype.Instance"></EntitySet>
        <EntitySet Name="Count" EntityType="Demo.ODataPrototype.Count" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Would anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The context in my JSON response defines the result as a collection of type IVserver.ODataPrototype.Count:

```
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:8080/ODataPrototype/ODataPrototype.svc/$metadata#Collection(IVserver.ODataPrototype.Count)"
```

But PowerQuery needs an entityset:

```
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:8080/ODataPrototype/ODataPrototype.svc/$metadata#Count"
```

The EntitySet "Count" must be declared in the EntityContainer.

To get the EntitySet in the @odata.context, an entityset must be set when building the ContextURL. Example:

```
final ContextURL contextURL = ContextURL.with().entitySet(responseEdmEntitySet).selectList(selectList).serviceRoot(baseURI).build();
```

And, the methods **asCollection()** and **type()** must **not** be called.